# What does degraded and undegraded text lines mean?

Tags: dataset, text-recognition

I have dataset which contains text lines. But some lines are labeled as undegraded and some with degraded.

What does this mean?
When does we need one of both in text recognition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Degradation:**
It means to reduce the quality of an image. It can be done by considering different parameters like: thresholding, jitter, sensitivity and elastic_elongation.